# PHP Codeigniter - Query loops Infinitely

Tags: php

I have a set of Lat-Long addresses, and a couple of circles & its radius saved in my database. I wanted to save in another table those addresses inside the circle radius, but whenever i run a query inside an if statement, it runs infinitely. I am new to PHP, and i really need help with this.

Sample Code :

```
foreach($jd as $join)
        {
            $ky = 40000 / 360;
            $rad = $join->circle_radius / 1000; (circle_radius is saved in meters )
            $kx = cos(pi() * $join->circle_lat / 180.0) * $ky;
            $dx = abs($join->circle_lng - $join->addr_longitude) * $kx;
            $dy = abs($join->circle_lat - $join->addr_latitude) * $ky;
            $res = sqrt($dx * $dx + $dy * $dy);
            if($res <= $rad)
            {
                var_dump($res);
                $data['list'] = array(
                    'id' => $join->id,
                    'affected_status' => "AFFECTED!",
                    'affected_cond' => "medium"
                );
                $this->main_model->addInsideCircle($data['list']);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean with it runs infinitely =)

Comment: Even if the expected output is 4, it loops, giving me 2k+ data inside the table. I'm sorry, ill have to edit the title, english isn't my native language.

Comment: Well I think that you need to debug line by line (`var_dump` every variable) to see if there is a mistake in the calculation.

Comment: The radius is 0.72 km, which should only print addresses below or with the same value, which it did. But the results keeps on repeating, basically it prints the same values over and over again

Comment: Maybe the `$jd` array has more rows than expected?